# Can we combine react naitve and IONIC?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-native, ionic2

can we combine IONIC for User interface and react native for device communication? I like to use IONIC styles for my app instead of writing my own.

Answer (score 4):

No not really. The closest thing that could be implemented would be to use a React Native [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) and render ionic css styling in the [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html), but it would be pretty complex for not a lot of payoff.

A lot of the built in styling that Ionic comes with is iOS and Android specific, matching the iOS and Android native apis and components. React Native also does this out of the box, so many components (Picker, DatePicker, AlertIOS, ProgressBarAndroid, TabBariOS, etc...) will already have platform specific styling similar to Ionic. The Ionic button styling, cards, etc can be custom built in React Native thought without a ton of effort.